# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing angular google maps

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to get a simple map working with angular using angular-google-maps and I keep getting this error

> "The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

I am using it with ASP.NET and have already tried adding the below code in WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

When I remove this file:

```
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
```

the error is gone but the map doesn't show. Any other thoughts as to why this is happening?